# Draw NSImage while space switching?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drawrect, spaces, nsimage

Currently in my project i've a simple nsimage which is updated via drawRect function.

I need to change the nsimage when the user switches between spaces... so i set my new image and called setNeedsDisplay when the NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification triggers.

The problem is that the drawRect method seems to be called to late... in other words, the previous image appears briefly before the new one. Is there any way to run the drawRect method while the transition between spaces is running? or any other way to accomplish the desired effect?

Thanks